# Clear all progress in Diablo: Hellfire

Tags: diablo, diablo-hellfire

I want to restart the game like I have never played it before. This is because I want the farmer to give me the auric amulet, and I want to play the game over. Even though I deleted all my characters and saves, I still see the cow instead of farmer when I start the game over at normal difficulty.

On top of that Ogden greets me with: "Thank goodness you've returned!" which just frustrates me and makes me want to feed him to the little demons that stole his sign.

Is there any way I can easily delete a file that stores the information about my progress in-game? If not, could I manipulate it with Cheat Engine somehow?  Hopefully that wont be necessary

Im not playing online so the file must be stored somewhere on the computer. So far none of the suggestions below worked.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the game?

Comment: Yes i did uninstall and reinstalled the game already.

Comment: @Xitcod13 if that didnt work i am pretty sure there is a diablo folder in your %appdata or in your private storage, as mentioned in my answer below

Answer (score 2):

From a response [here](http://www.techimo.com/forum/general-gaming-discussion/26536-can-you-move-saved-games-diablo.html)

> As of (the latest) patch 1.09 for the original Diablo game the save
>   game files are now located in the install directory. The naming format
>   is: multi_0.sv, multi_1.sv, etc for multi-player and single_0.sv,
>   single_1.sv, etc for single player.

Deleting those files should set you back to the beginning.  Since you said that you had already deleted the install folder and your characters were still there, I'm guessing maybe you hadn't patched your installation.  Try upgrading to 1.09 (or whatever the latest patch is now) and then see if the save files show up there.

Comment: ok so this solution actually doesnt work. What i did and forgot is removed the cowquest from the Command.txt The game still thinks i have played before but it cannot show the cowquest as it is disabled in the command file. Although my main problem is fixed i would still like the game to believe i never played before.

Comment: @Xit Wouldn't uninstalling have restored that file?  Were you able to locate the save files after upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your installation folder of rhe game for something like `savegames` or have a look in your %appdata folder, there might be a diablo folder.... just delet it

Otherwise unnstall the game, let CCleaner run twice (most efficient cleaning tool imo), use the win-search-engine and check for stayed files, delete them too, and reinstall it in another place.

Comment: Let's nuke the site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure!

Comment: @Adriano Varoli Piazza And what do you do if the target is nit on the site we hit? Nuking the rest, too? Then i prefer precison, instead of  mass destruction

Comment: I could not find the diablo folder in the %appdaata I could not find a sierra folder nor hellfire folder neither.

Comment: @Xitcod13 Sry, then there is just one option left.... thers no way for you to access the saves... then they lay on servers, you are playing on... no way of restarting it seems, the only way were to create a new account

Comment: Im not playing online. It must be there just not in those folders. (I deleted the folder of installation after uninstall so im sure that the data is not stored there, also my characters appear after i reinstall the game)

Comment: @Xitcod13 .... use the win search engine try to find hellsp_0.hsv

Comment: searched for the "hellsp_0.hsv" with the search non-indexed location selected it turned out no search results. I also searched for hellsp just in case with the same disappointing outcome.

Comment: Ill get the game on my own, then i will have a lool, so please be a little more patient